# C++ - Build Order and Dependency Problem

Tags: c++

I seem to be misunderstanding something related to build order dependencies in C++.  So I have this code, which defines a class that I use as a functionoid (object whose purpose is to substitute for passing a function pointer):

```
#include "Imports.h"

class X: public Y
{
public:

    X (T* t) { this->t= t; }
    virtual ~X(){}

    virtual void draw()
    {
        if (t->booleanReturningFunction())
        {
                t->someField.draw();
        }
    }

    T* t;
};
```

I'm getting a compiler error that complains about the "use of undefined type T" at the line numbers where I'm using T.  However, Imports.h looks like:

```
//The goal of this file is to have all the typcally needed imports in one place.

#if !defined(IMPORTS_H)
#define IMPORTS_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

class T;
class X;
class Y;

#include "Y.h"
#include "X.h"
#include "T.h"

#endif // if !defined(IMPORTS_H)
```

With each ".h" file containing a definition of that class.  Now T actually does have an X object in it (not a pointer, but an X object).  But, as far as I can tell, there's no circular dependency in the build order because X only has a pointer to T, right?  Is there anything I'm missing that you can see just from this code?  Help is much appreciated!

**Edit:** I solved my problem. The issue was that I was doing the above code inside a header file. The compiler understandably couldn't compile t->booleanReturningFunction() based on a forward reference (it needed to see the class declaration to know what address to bind the function call to).

Comment: Generally you don't want all your includes for your classes in one place. it will make your project very unmanageable.

Comment: I understand that, but this is how this project already is and I don't feel like reworking it at this point unless it's absolutely necessary.  I just want the specific error I'm having to go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. The issue was that I was doing the above code inside a header file. The compiler understandably couldn't compile t->booleanReturningFunction() based on a forward reference (it needed to see the class declaration to know what address to bind the function call to).

Answer (score 1):

> Now T actually does have an X object in it (not a pointer, but an X object).

Given this order -

```
class T;
class X;
class Y;

#include "Y.h"
#include "T.h"   // 1
#include "X.h"
```

`T.h` has a `X` object as you mentioned. Until this point (`1`) compiler doesn't know the definition of class `X`. For the object to instantiate compiler should see the full class definition just not the forward declaration of `X`. But it seems strange that the compiler is complaining about undefined type `T`.

Comment: Sorry, I got that wrong.  It's `"Y.h"`, `"X.h"`, and only then `"T.h"`.  I've edited my post.  That's why this build order problem I'm having isn't making much sense to me.  Is the fact that the `X` instance is invoking a method on the `T` instance (as shown in my code above), or using a field of such an instance (via pointer) relevant in any way?

Comment: Nevermind.  I solved my problem.  The issue was that I was doing the above code inside a header file.  The compiler understandably couldn't compile `t->booleanReturningFunction()` based on a forward reference (it needed to see the class declaration to know what address to bind the function call to).

Comment: Done.  Can't accept it for two days, stack overflow says.  I didn't know accepting your own answer was even possible.